# Shifting Window Frame without moving its contents in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, window, frame

I have (+) and (-) buttons... The (+) button should make the window longer in the downward direction, and the (-) button should undo what the (+) button did, by making it shorter from the bottom.

The point is, the frame should only be getting stretched from the bottom and most of the UI items should be staying in place - there are buttons on the bottom of the window that should follow the change in window height...

The problem is I'm using this to shift the window and sustain the same position of its contents...

```
NSRect frame = sender.window.frame;
NSLog(@"\nHeight and width of window frame: (%f,%f).\nThe x and y origin of the window frame: (%f,%f). ", frame.size.height, frame.size.width, frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y);
frame.origin.y -= 22;
frame.size.height += 22;
[sender.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:NO];

NSRect viewFrame = mainView.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= 22;
viewFrame.size.height += 22;
mainView.frame = viewFrame;
```

But say you click the (+) button once; all the items shift up slightly while the frame gets longer. If you click (+) consecutively after the first press it will function as expected: the frame will move down and its contents will stay in place. 
If you then clicked the (-) button once; all the items shift down slightly while the frame gets shortened. Clicking the (-) consecutively after the first press, it will just move the frame as expected.

It seems pressing the button the first time will move all the windows contents, while consecutive presses will function as intended... I'd like to know if I'm missing something about autosizing in the Interface Editor of XCode. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [mainWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush];
[mainWindow disableFlushWindow];

NSRect frame = sender.window.frame;
NSRect viewFrame = mainView.frame;

viewFrame.size.height += 25;
frame.size.height += 25;
frame.origin.y -= 25;

[sender.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:NO];
mainView.frame = viewFrame;

[mainWindow enableFlushWindow];
```

This works fine. I couldn't get the NSView and the window linked so I just move them both manually and use disableFlushWindow to make it happen seamlessly at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mainView` is the main view in your window, you should not be modifying its frame manually. So long as you have your springs and struts (or constraints) configured properly, it should resize automatically with the window.